# Possible editing of Salesforce generated HTML

Tags: html, salesforce

I apologize in advance because I am an extreme novice, but I am trying to help get a website launched and I have to help design this one page which asks for input from the user which will be converted to Salesforce data.

For instance, I want to change some of the headings to be more descriptive and I’d like to add more verbiage to help explain what I want.  Am I able to do either of those things?  Also, the last field - “Please Explain”  Should be listed beside the option “Other” above it - can I move it to beside “Other”?

```
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: Please add the following <META> element to your page <HEAD>.      -->
<!--  If necessary, please modify the charset parameter to specify the        -->
<!--  character set of your HTML page.                                        -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: Please add the following <FORM> element to your page.             -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

<input type=hidden name="oid" value="00Di0000000cMJ7">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://www.hearttutoring.org">

<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: These fields are optional debugging elements. Please uncomment    -->
<!--  these lines if you wish to test in debug mode.                          -->
<!--  <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1>                              -->
<!--  <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail"                                  -->
<!--  value="eelliott@hearttutoring.org">                                     -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<label for="first_name">First Name</label><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="email">Email</label><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="company">Company</label><input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" /><br>

What time would you like to tutor? *:<select  id="00Ni000000DN633" multiple="multiple" name="00Ni000000DN633" title="What time would you like to tutor? *"><option value="7:45 - 8:45 AM">7:45 - 8:45 AM</option>
<option value="1:15 - 2:15 PM (Winterfield only)">1:15 - 2:15 PM (Winterfield only)</option>
<option value="1:45 - 2:45 PM (Billingsville only)">1:45 - 2:45 PM (Billingsville only)</option>
<option value="~1:30 - 2:30 PM (no school preference)">~1:30 - 2:30 PM (no school preference)</option>
<option value="No preference">No preference</option>
</select><br>

Which days are you available?:<select  id="00Ni000000CMuNZ" multiple="multiple" name="00Ni000000CMuNZ" title="Which days are you available?"><option value="Monday">Monday</option>
<option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
<option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
<option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select><br>

How long are you available?:<select  id="00Ni000000CMuJr" name="00Ni000000CMuJr" title="How long are you available?"><option value="">--None--</option><option value="1 Hour (2 Sessions)">1 Hour (2 Sessions)</option>
<option value="30 Minutes (1 Session)">30 Minutes (1 Session)</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select><br>

At which school would you like to tutor?:<select  id="00Ni000000DN63S" name="00Ni000000DN63S" title="At which school would you like to tutor?"><option value="">--None--</option><option value="Billingsville Elementary">Billingsville Elementary</option>
<option value="Winterfield Elementary">Winterfield Elementary</option>
<option value="No preference">No preference</option>
</select><br>

Other scheduling preferences:<textarea  id="00Ni000000CMubb" name="00Ni000000CMubb" type="text" wrap="soft"></textarea><br>

How did you hear about HEART Tutoring?:<select  id="00Ni000000CMuJ8" name="00Ni000000CMuJ8" title="How did you hear about HEART Tutoring?"><option value="">--None--</option><option value="I am a returning HEART Tutor">I am a returning HEART Tutor</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select><br>

Please Explain:<textarea  id="00Ni000000DN63r" name="00Ni000000DN63r" type="text" wrap="soft"></textarea><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

The main thing I’m worried about is if I mess with Field Labels in this code, will they not be able to connect back to the corresponding fields in Sales Force. Even if I could just add some descriptions underneath or beside the field names that would be helpful…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change anything within the `<label>` tag.
For example:

```
<label for="first_name">First Name</label><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>
```

Can be:

```
<label for="first_name">Anything I want in here</label><input  id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>
```

It's also ok to move field positions, it doesn't matter where they are in the page as long as the IDs are not altered.